# How to repair a corrupted microsd card?

Tags: windows, micro-sd-card

My MicroSD card was working and now it isn't. I do not care to retrieve the files. When I plug it into my computer (using a usb adapter) it shows up but doesn't show any details and asks to be formatted:

[image]

It also shows as 30.6 MB when it is actually 64 GB. It failed when trying to format.

I then tried to use diskpart and got this error:

[image]

So then I tried to use chkdsk:

[image]

Is this microsd card shot or can it be repaired? Or if it is repaired will it be unreliable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your drive is dead. SD cards are consumables, really. When their partitions disappear spontaneously and they report the wrong size they are dead.

Comment: Say it ain't so! This one had fairly low mileage. I just needed to hear it from someone else to believe it.

Comment: @gomapping Even if [SD Memory Card Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/index.html) makes it work, do you really want to be using a memory card that could lose everything at any time without warning?

Comment: No it's not. This happens a lot and it can be fixed by erasing the cards' partition from the Disk Management window, and re-creating the partition again.

Comment: I have an admittedly small sample size of perhaps a dozen SD cards of a variety of brands and models and use cases over the past 10 years or so, and first of all, losing partitions and reporting wrong sizes has not happened with any frequency. Second, each time it did happen erasing partitions, reformatting, and other repair methods did not cause the cards to start working again.