# MicroSD Card Went From 512 GB to 30.6 MB

Tags: partitioning, memory, formatting

I have been using this card for the past 20 months without any problems. I was able to use all the memory (and even checked the card with H2testw with no errors). Recently I was using the card with a card writer and I belive it somehow got pulled out while it was being used. Since then the card doesn't show the 2 partitions that was on there and all it shows is 30.6 MB instead of the original 512 GB.

I have searched the net and tried numerous solutions found but nothing works. I get the same results reported [here.](https://superuser.com/questions/1505877/how-to-repair-a-corrupted-microsd-card) additional options I tried. With all the options I was only able to see the 30.6 MB and it wasn't even able to make a partition or format that.

1. Format with Windows Disk Manager. Result "format failed"
2. Mini Tool Partition Wizard.
3. DiskGenious.
4. AOMEI Partition Assistant
5. R-Studio
6. And some more that I don't remember.

Since this seems to have happened because of removal of card while in use I was wondering if someone knows of a solution to bring it back to life. This was a fairly expensive card. and I would like to get it back to life.

Comment: https://blog.balena.io/did-etcher-break-my-usb-sd-card/ try diskpart (scroll down a bit)

Comment: Did you try this [one](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/sd-memory-card-formatter-for-windows-download/), see Accept bottom of the page?

Comment: @Gantendo I tried DiskPart and my results was the same as reported at this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6k4X.png

Comment: @Sylvain Yes result was a message that it wasn't able to format.

Comment: @Sruly Can you try to create a smaller partition with partition wizard, for ex 15MB. Then use the same diskpart procedure to clean and create primary, then format? Also, maybe a surface test on disk genius? But I'm sure you tried many things. Removing those while powered or writing can be very bad for those fragile things.

Comment: If the answer below doesn't work then you'll have to accept this answer in your linked Q&A as the one and only: https://superuser.com/a/1505934/653259

Comment: Is ther any way to force any of these tools (or maybe a linux tool) to see it as a bigger card? If I'm able to do this I may be able then to create a partition and format it to it's full capacity. As of now I can't even create any partition even a small size